# Law convergence and Levy

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, weak-convergence

Let $X_n$ be a random variable that converges weakly to some $X$. In my case $X\sim N(0,1)$ I want to prove that 
$E[e^{kX_n}] \to E[e^{kX}]$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

I've heard that this is a corollary of Levy's theorem but I cannot track down which, mainly because levy's corollary is a slang term. Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: Lévy's continuity theorem gives $\mathbb{E}(e^{i \xi X_n}) \to \mathbb{E}(e^{i \xi X})$ for any $\xi \in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot prove such convergence without stronger assumptions; even almost sure convergence does not guarantee it.

E.g. it is enough to assume that $\sup_n E[e^{aX_n}]<\infty$ for some $a>k$ and use [de la Vallee-Poussin theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_integrability#Relevant_theorems).